# I'm trying to run the same code twice from a compiler I bought online

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 games in this current code, *I got the first 2 to work but the third has been elusive*. I would like to have it all run simultaneously but it doesn't have to. The last 2 games are from the same compiler. These are interactive games like crosswords and word searches. Also, I'm new to js, I'm still learning. Here's my code.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="Crossword Compiler (www.crossword-compiler.com)">
<br></br>
<center><p style="font-size:20px">Word Match Game</p></center>
<br></br>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/s/style.css">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
        
        <script src="/s/mayavocabagjQtest.js"></script>
        
    </head>
        
        <body>
            <div id="cardslots">
                <div id="draggableBlocks"></div>
                <div id="targetArea"></div>
                <div id="message">Match!</div>
                <div id="successMessage">Success!</div>
            </div>
        </body>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<center><p style="font-size:20px">Crossword Puzzle</p></center>
<br></br>
<TITLE>Crossword Puzzle</TITLE>
<br></br>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
BODY, .Clues, .GridClues { font-size: -3pt; font-family: Times New Roman,Times; }
-->
</style>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--

div#CrosswordCompilerPuz {
    position: fixed;
    transform: scale(1.4);
    left: 22%;
    width: 700px; // Any width will be fine
    height: 700px; // Any height will be fine
}
.PuzTitle {
 font-size: 15pt; color: #800000; font-weight: bold;
 }
.CopyTag {
 font-size: 10pt; color: #000000
 }
-->
</STYLE>
<TITLE>Crossword Puzzle</TITLE>

</HEAD>

<BODY TEXT="#000000" BGCOLOR="#ffffff">

<script src="/s/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="/s/crosswordCompiler.js"></script>
<script src="/s/mayaagcw.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){ 
$("#CrosswordCompilerPuz").CrosswordCompiler(CrosswordPuzzleData,null,    {SUBMITMETHOD:"POST",SUBMIT   :   "",PROGRESS :  "" , ROOTIMAGES: "CrosswordCompilerApp/CrosswordImages/"  } );});</script>
<div id="CrosswordCompilerPuz"></div>


<center><P><BLOCKQUOTE><A CLASS="PDFURL" HREF="testcwp.pdf">PDF</A></BLOCKQUOTE></center>

<HR>
<SPAN CLASS="CopyTag">Web page created by <A HREF="http://www.crossword-compiler.com/">Crossword Compiler</A>.</SPAN>
</BODY>
  <BODY>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta NAME="Generator" CONTENT="Crossword Compiler (www.crossword-compiler.com)">

<style type="text/css">
<!--
BODY, .Clues, .GridClues { font-size: -3pt; font-family: Times New Roman,Times; }
-->
</style>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--
div#CrosswordCompilerPuz1 {
    position: fixed;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    left: 22%;
    width: 700px; // Any width will be fine
    height: 700px; // Any height will be fine
}
.PuzTitle {
 font-size: 15pt; color: #800000; font-weight: bold;
 }
.CopyTag {
 font-size: 10pt; color: #000000
 }
-->
</STYLE>
<TITLE>Wordsearch</TITLE>

</BODY>
<BODY TEXT="#000000" BGCOLOR="#ffffff">

<script src="/s/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="/s/crosswordCompiler.js"></script>
<script src="/s/1.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){ $("#CrosswordCompilerPuz1").CrosswordCompiler(CrosswordPuzzleData,null,    {SUBMITMETHOD:"POST",PROGRESS :  "" , ROOTIMAGES: "CrosswordCompilerApp/CrosswordImages/"  } );});</script>
<div id="CrosswordCompilerPuz1"></div>

<HR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

any input is appreciated

Comment: What's wrong? Where is the problem?

Comment: This 2nd and 3rd game conflict with one another bc theyre both from the same compiler